# Cartesian Products on Lists

Tags: c#

I am struggling to create a Cartesian product of lists due to a compile error.

The extension method works a treat if the input is IEnumerable, but struggles if it is a list.

The return type must be lists.

The below code throws a compile error on `sequence`

```
public static List<List<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this List<List<T>> sequences, Func<T, T> aggregateFunct)
{
    List<List<T>> emptyProduct = new List<List<T>> { new List<T>() };
    return sequences.Aggregate(
      emptyProduct,
      (accumulator, sequence) =>
        from accseq in accumulator
        from item in sequence // CS1943
        select accseq.AddRange(new List<T> { aggregateFunct(item) }));
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1943  An expression of type 'List<T>' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'List<List<T>>'.  Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'.  Maths   ...\Maths.cs    17  Active`

Comment: A side note, method `.AddRange` returns `void` so it is unlikely that you can use `select` with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you would want to change the method. It can be used on ANY `IEnumerable<T>`, not just `List<T>`. 
If you need a List of Lists, then just call `.ToList()` on the result:

```
...CartesianProduct().Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```

And keep the original method as is:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    return sequences.Aggregate(emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) =>
            from acc in accumulator
            from item in sequence
            select acc.Concat(new[] { item }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `AddRange` returns `void` and thus your `select` statement is invalid. You can create and extensions method similar to `AddRange` but with return value and update your code as following

```
private static List<T> AddRangeReturn<T>(this List<T> list, IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    list.AddRange(items);

    return list;
}

public static List<List<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(List<List<T>> sequences, Func<T, T> aggregateFunct)
{
    List<List<T>> emptyProduct = new List<List<T>> { new List<T>() };
    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) =>
            (from accseq in accumulator
            from item in sequence // CS1943
            select accseq.AddRangeReturn(new List<T> { aggregateFunct(item) })).ToList());
}
```